# Java DOM: How to add a namespace with a specific prefix?

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to build a simple XML DOM in Java for Android. This works fine but the Android namespace prefix is always set to "ns0" but it should be "android"

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

Element manifest = doc.createElement("manifest");
manifest.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:android",NS_ANDROID);
manifest.setAttributeNS(NS_ANDROID, "versionName", "bla");
doc.appendChild(manifest);
```

The output I get is the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ns0:versionName="bla"/>
```

What do I need to change to get the following result:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:versionName="bla"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setAttributeNS()` method requires a *QName*. In your second call you passed an unqualified attribute name, so a default prefix (`ns0`) was added to it. Since you called it twice, you got two attributes.

To obtain the result you expect, you just have to call `setAttributeNS()` once with a *qualified* attribute name:

```
Element manifest = doc.createElement("manifest");
manifest.setAttributeNS(NS_ANDROID, "android:versionName", "bla");
doc.appendChild(manifest);
```